# Is f is one -one ? true/false

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta ,r\sin\theta)$ for $(r,\theta)$ $\in \mathbb R^2$ with $r\ne0$.

then which are true statements?

a) f is  one -one on {($r$,$\theta$) ∈  $R^{2}$: $r\ne0$ }

b)for any ($r$,$\theta$) $\in$  $\mathbb R^2$  with $r\ne0$ ,f is one -one on a neighbourhood of ($r$,$\theta$)

my attempts :i know that determinant |Df($r$,$\theta$)| = $r\ne0$  that mean it is invertible and one- one and onto function  exist,,,as i think both option A)  and option B) is true because both are invertible,,,,,

Is my answer is correct or not ? pliz verified and tell me the solution...i would be more thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

a) No. $f(1,0)=f(1,2\pi)$.

b) Yes. Fix $\theta $. We can suppose WLOG that in $]0,\infty [\times ]\theta-\pi ,\theta +\pi[$ it's one to one. I let you prove that.

Answer (score 4):

What happen for the points $(\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{4})$ and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, $\frac{-\pi}{4})$ ?

In the order pair for $\mathbb{R}$$^2$ these points are different but they take the function to the same range value which is $(\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{-1}{2}$$)$.

So in general it may not be one to one.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), $f$ is not injective since for any $(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(r,\theta)=f(r,\theta+2\pi)$.

You have the right idea for (b): you are using the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: thanks a lot @ A.Goodier